# Nested `accepts_nested_attributes_for` hitting `undefined method 'with_indifferent_access'`

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm writing specs for creating a new account. Here's the situation:

Ruby 2.5.0, Rails 5.2.0.rc1

```
class Account
  has_many :accounts_users, inverse_of: :account
  has_many :users, through: :accounts_users
  has_one :owner, -> { AccountsUser.admins.order(:id) }, class_name: 'AccountsUser'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
end

class AccountsUser
  belongs_to :account, inverse_of: :accounts_user
  belongs_to :user, autosave: true, inverse_of: :accounts_user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

class User
  has_many :accounts, through: :accounts_users
  has_many :accounts_users, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :accounts_users, reject_if: :all_blank
end

# AccountsController#account_create_params
params.require(:account).permit(
  :plan_id,
  :name,
  :subdomain,
  {
    owner_attributes: {
      user_attributes: [
        :email,
        :first_name,
        :last_name
      ]
    }
  }
)

# rspec account_create_params
let(:valid_account_params) do
  {
    plan_id: plan.id,
    name: 'Name',
    subdomain: 'subdomain',
    owner_attributes: {
      user_attributes: [
        email: 'jane@doe.com',
        first_name: 'Jane',
        last_name: 'Doe'
      ]
    }
  }
end

@account = Account.new(account_create_params)
#> NoMethodError: undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for #<Array:0x000056472e0799c0>
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.2.0.rc1/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:412:in `assign_nested_attributes_for_one_to_one_association'
```

It has to be complaining about the `user_attributes` array, and seeing as it's coming from a method called `assign_nested_attributes_for_one_to_one_association`, Rails seems to be erroneously thinking that the relationship between AccountsUsers and Users is one to one and not one to many.

I've triple checked the associations. What do you guys think? Rails 5.2 bug perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

There were several issues here. I found that permitting parameters and providing them needed different syntax:

```
def account_create_params
  params.require(:account).permit(
    :plan_id,
    :name,
    :subdomain,
    {
      owner_attributes: {
        user_attributes: [
          :email,
          :first_name,
          :last_name,
          :password
        ]
      }
    }
  )
end
```

vs

```
let(:valid_account_params) do
  {
    plan_id: plan.id,
    name: 'Name',
    subdomain: 'subdomain',
    owner_attributes: {
      user_attributes: {
        email: email_valid,
        first_name: 'Jane',
        last_name: 'Doe',
        password: 'password'
      }
    }
  }
end
```

A bit confusing there but it works. The `inverse_of` on AccountsUser was wrong. I needed plural:

```
belongs_to :account, inverse_of: :accounts_users, optional: true
belongs_to :user, autosave: true, inverse_of: :accounts_users
```

And I also needed optional: true on the account belongs to, despite accepts_nested_attributes_for setting up the relationship properly. There was a chicken vs egg situation where the AccountsUser was invalid because the Account didn't exist, and the Account couldn't be saved because the AccountsUser was invalid. This may be a Rails 5 'feature'.